# Как найти индексы максимальной суммы элементов в непрерывном участке массива на C++?

Tags: c++

> Вам даётся массив целых чисел. Необходимо найти такие два индекса i и j в этом массиве, что сумма a[i], a[i+1], a[i+2], … a[j] будет максимально возможной и вывести их.
>
> Пример:
>
> a = {-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4}
>
> Тогда наибольшая сумма последовательных элементов находится между индексами 3 и 6: {4,-1,2,1}, сумма = 6. Необходимо вывести 3 и 6

Comment: Ну если ничего умнее в голову не приходит — то хотя бы переберите все возможные пары (i,j) и посмотрите, когда будет наибольшая сумма...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(0, "");

    int a[] = {-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4};
    int i = 0, j = 0, iMax = 0, jMax = 0, sumMax = 0, sumTemp = 0;

    for (; i < size(a); i++) {

        sumTemp = a[i];

        for (int j = i + 1; j < size(a); ++j) {
            sumTemp += a[j];
            if (sumTemp > sumMax) {
                iMax = i;
                jMax = j;
                sumMax = sumTemp;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Значение индексов " << iMax << " и " << jMax << " Сумма " << sumMax;
    return 0;
}
```

решение тривиальное, и далеко не оптимальное. Простой перебор с проверками

Comment: Серьёзно? Такую задачу за квадрат решать?

Comment: Да ещё и неправильно. i и j должны быть одинаковыми если в массиве только отрицательные числа.

Comment: Если ни кто не даёт правильный ответ или просто не отвечает - дайте не правильный, и найдётся куча народу желающих исправить :)))

Comment: Так я ж описал алгоритм в ответе ;)

Answer (score 0):

Линейное решение:

0. Если неотрицательных чисел в массиве нет, выбираем максимальный элемент и оба индекса ставим на него.
1. Проходим по элементам массива и считаем баланс.
2. Если текущий элемент неотрицательный и баланс 0, то запоминаем индекс начала последовательности.
3. Если текущий элемент отрицательный, сравниваем текущий баланс с лучшим и при необходимости заменяем установив концом отрезка прошлый элемент.
4. Текущий элемент добавляем к балансу.
5. Если баланс получился отрицательным, заменяем на 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a[] = { -2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4 };
    const int n = std::size(a);
    int answer = a[0],
        firstPos = 0,
        secondPos = 0,
        sum = 0,
        minimum = 0,
        min_pos = -1;
    for (int r = 0; r < n; ++r) {
        sum += a[r];

        int cur = sum - minimum;
        if (cur > answer) {
            answer = cur;
            firstPos = min_pos + 1;
            secondPos = r;
        }

        if (sum < minimum) {
            minimum = sum;
            min_pos = r;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Summ: " << answer <<
        std::endl << "First Index: " << firstPos <<
        std::endl << "Second Index: " << secondPos;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]